# NodeJS Typescript doesn't convert to relative path

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have Node project with Typescript.

I want to import this module in **getToken.ts**

```
import {apiRoot} from '@App/utils/apiRoot';
```

For absolute path I have a config like this.

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es2016", 
 "module": "commonjs",
 "baseUrl": "./",
 "paths": {
    "@App/*": [ "src/*"]
  },
 "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"], 
 "outDir": "./dist", 
 "esModuleInterop": true,   
 "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
 "strict": true,   
 "skipLibCheck": true 
}
```

**tsconfig.build.json**

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": [
      "__test__/**/*.spec.ts",
      "__test__/**/*.test.ts"
    ]
}
```

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon dist/index.js\"",
},
```

When I run **npm run dev**

I got an error

> Error: Cannot find module '@App/utils/apiRoot'

I check to build file in dist folder (**getToken.js**) and I see

```
const apiRoot_1 = require("@App/utils/apiRoot");
```

I use same technic and same path for testing with Jest without a problem in same project. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: This has been a problem in TypeScript for a very, very long time: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433